# Information does not go into my table

Tags: php, sql, database, html

I am having trouble with a some php code. I was able to get the code to work on my test website. I am now trying to register a user with a popup register menu. When I enter the information and click on my register button nothing is sent to my database table. 
Heres my code.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>untitled.com</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="frontPage.css">   
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/general.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>   
</head>
<body>

<h1> untitled </h1>

<h2> description of website</h2>

<div id="wrapper">
<nav id="nav">
    <ul id="navigation">
        <a class="button" href="" >Login</a>        
        <div class="popup">     
            <a href="#" class="close">CLOSE</a>         
            <form>
                <P><span class="title">Username</span> <input name="" type="text" /></P>
                <P><span class="title">Password</span> <input name="" type="password" /></P>
                <P><input name="" type="button" value="Login" /></P>
            </form>         
        </div>
    </ul>
</nav>


<?php
 require('db.php');

 if (isset($_POST['username'])){
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $city = $_POST['city'];
 $state = $_POST['state'];
 $zip = $_POST['zip'];
 $phone = $_POST['phone'];;
 $query = "INSERT into `users` (username, password, email, city, state, zip, phone) VALUES ('$username', '".md5($password)."', '$email', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$phone' )";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 if($result){
 echo "<div class='form'><h3>You are registered successfully.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
 }
 }else{
?>



        <a class="Regbutton" href="#" >Register</a>         
        <div class="Regpopup">      
            <a href="#" class="close">CLOSE</a>         
            <form>
                <P><span class="title">Username</span> <input name="username" type="text" /></P>
                <P><span class="title">Password</span> <input name="password" type="password" /></P>
                <P><span class="title">Email</span> <input name="email" type="email" /></P>
                <P><span class="title">City</span> <input name="city" type="text" /></P>
                <P><span class="title">State</span> <input name="state" type="text" maxlength="2" /></P>
                <P><span class="title">zip</span> <input name="zip" type="text" maxlength="5" /></P>
                <P><span class="title">phone</span> <input name="phone" type="text" maxlength="15"/></P>
                <P><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" /></P>
            </form>
    </div>


<?php } ?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you forgot to fill <input name="???"... I mean <input name="username"... and <input name="password"...

Comment: `<form>` makes a `GET` request to current page. Use `method` attribute to define method of form processing. You also are open to SQL injections.

Comment: Thanks! I  was overlooking it and it works now. I really do not know what SQL injections are.

Comment: Sidenote: This isn't a live site or intended to go live, *right?*

Comment: Because, MD5 is as old as the chair I'm sitting on, and that's the only thing that can be trusted. They don't make them like they used to, I'll tell ya ;-)

Comment: You have very serious security issues with this. Using mysql (which is outdated). You should now be using mysqli or PDO. Also, do not use md5 for passwords. You should use PHP's password_hash function instead.

Comment: @kojow7 *with a prepared statement* of course ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the information everyone. I haven't messed around with mysql for awhile I and I trying relearn it.

Comment: Yes, using mysqli or PDO **with** prepared statements is a must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value from input field by post method, it is important to define form method. Example

```
<form action="" method="POST">
</form>
```

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you! I need to work on my login button now.